# Cannot decrypt C# encrypted message using node-rsa npm

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography, rsa, node-rsa

I've got a server written in node.js that I want to receive encrypted messages from a C# app. I tried to implement `RSA` firstly for this task, but with no avail, because I wasn't able to decrypt the message after being encrypted by the C# app using the keys generated by the server.

I've tried using the node-rsa npm for generating the keys on the server side and got this error when trying to decrypt the messages

> "Error during decryption (probably incorrect key). Original error:
>   Error: Incorrect data or key".

I've also tried the crypto module for decrypting, but received this error instead

> "error:0406506C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater
>   than mod len".

The C# app is a console app as it is merely used for testing the encryption, which uses the `RSAServiceProvider` for importing the keys generated by the server(which are stored in the pem format), encrypting the message(or the key, if I am going to implement `AES` as well) and then sending it back to the server by writing it in a file.

This is the `rsa-wrapper.js` file which contains the `rsa` implementation:

```
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
const fs = require('fs');

var key;

var generate = function () {
    key = new NodeRSA();
    key.generateKeyPair(2048, 65537);
    fs.writeFileSync('./keys/public-key.pem', key.exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem'));
};

var encrypt = function (message) {
    let encrypted = key.encrypt(message, 'base64');
    return encrypted;
};

var decrypt = function (cipherText) {
  let decrypted = key.decrypt(cipherText, 'utf8');
  return decrypted;
}

module.exports.generate = generate;
module.exports.test = test;
module.exports.encrypt = encrypt;
module.exports.decrypt = decrypt;
```

This is the the app.js file which simply contains the GET functions for testing the encryption:

```
const express = require('express');
const rsaWrapper = require('./components/rsa-wrapper.js');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

app.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Working');
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/generate', function(req, res) {
    rsaWrapper.generate();
    console.log('The keys have been generated successfully.');
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/decrypt', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./cipher-text.txt', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The original message is:' + rsaWrapper.decrypt(data));
    });
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

This is the console app written in C# for encrypting the message using the public key generated by the server:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
            String publicKey = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\NodeProjects\Test project\keys\public-key.pem").Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
            publicKey = publicKey.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
            publicKey = publicKey.Replace("\r", String.Empty);
            publicKey = publicKey.Replace("\t", String.Empty);
            rsaParam.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
            byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(65537);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(intBytes);
            rsaParam.Exponent = intBytes;
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);

            string msg = ".";
            byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg), true);
            string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\NodeProjects\Test project\cipher-text.txt", cipherText);

            Console.WriteLine(publicKey);
            Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And this is the second rsa-wrapper.js that I tried using, but also resulting in a failure:

```
const rsaWrapper = {};
const fs = require('fs');
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// load keys from file
rsaWrapper.initLoadServerKeys = () => {
    rsaWrapper.serverPub = fs.readFileSync('./keys/public-key.pem');
    rsaWrapper.serverPrivate = fs.readFileSync('./keys/private-key.pem');
};

rsaWrapper.generate = () => {
    let key = new NodeRSA();
    key.generateKeyPair(2048, 65537);
    fs.writeFileSync('./keys/private-key.pem', key.exportKey('pkcs8-private-pem'));
    fs.writeFileSync('./keys/public-key.pem', key.exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem'));

    return true;
};

rsaWrapper.serverExampleEncrypt = () => {
    console.log('Server public encrypting');

    let enc = rsaWrapper.encrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPub, 'Server init hello');
    console.log('Encrypted RSA string ', '\n', enc);
    let dec = rsaWrapper.decrypt(rsaWrapper.serverPrivate, enc);
    console.log('Decrypted RSA string ...');
    console.log(dec);
};

rsaWrapper.encrypt = (publicKey, message) => {
    let enc = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: publicKey,
        padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, Buffer.from(message));
    return enc.toString('base64');
};

rsaWrapper.decrypt = (privateKey, message) => {
    let enc = crypto.privateDecrypt({
        key: privateKey,
        padding: crypto.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
    }, Buffer.from(message, 'base64'));

    return enc.toString();
};

module.exports = rsaWrapper;
```

Comment: So your `decrypt` method simply specifies the key and padding; and your SERVER side encrypt method uses KEY as modulues and a BitConverter provided array taken from a static constant of 65537 as Exponent. Since you are not constructing the RSA parameters the same way in decrypt, it is no wonder that you can't decrypt anything.

Comment: As a side note, this is a VERY strange way to encrypt things. Firstly, RSA by itself can only encrypt data up to keysize/8 (e.g. 2048 key would encrypt up to 214 bytes), which means this is only really well suited to things like passwords etc. Secondly, if you do have a PEM file, convert it to PKCS12 and just load the RSACryptoServiceProvider like so: `var key = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Wherever.pfx");
           var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)key.PrivateKey;`

Comment: Lastly, if you CAN change encryption, i would recommend switching to PKCS7 aka CMS - see e.g. `EnvelopedCMS` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.envelopedcms?view=netframework-4.8

This is industry standard and i am pretty sure there'd be a plugin for node to read this. If you need a cipher, pick DES3-CBC.

Comment: I have just checked and you are right. I forgot that the pem file contains the entire public key, not just the modulus, so I will need to address this problem and see if it will work. Also, as I have already said, I plan on implementing a symmetric encryption algorithm for the messages, but I'd still need to use the RSA for sending the key securely. Or am I wrong? I haven't delved too much into cryptography, so I don't know the details, just how it works on the surface. And I'll only send small pieces of text, so I thought that the length limitations wouldn't be a problem regardless.

Comment: Also, thanks for your help. I'll come with an update soon.

Comment: You were right, that was the problem. I've rewritten the way the public key is imported and now it works accordingly. Thanks a lot!